# Count of unread emails in Gmail

Tags: c#, gmail

i am using Google provisioning API (education edition) and I am thinking of allowing users to allow access to their email directly from my application without them logging in.

I have accomplished that so far but I also want to display the count of unread emails within my application. I can't find that within the API.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Are you trying to prove Zawinski's law?  http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html   :)

Comment: can you post a link to the api? I'm guessing it returns xml? if so, can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing your application in Python? 
If so, take a look at [gmail notifier](http://gmail-notify.sourceforge.net/index.php). 
It's a python app for linux desktops, but it keeps a count of unread messages.

Hope that helps.